# chmod ninja.sh failed: Operation not permitted when building AOSP

Tags: android-source, fedora, ninja

I'm on Fedora Linux. When I build AOSP (crDroid to be specific) using the command `mka bacon -j12` or with `brunch judypn` as advised by the crDroid manifest, it gives me the error `chmod ninja.sh failed: Operation not permitted. ckati failed with: exit status 1`. There is literally *nothing* in out/error.log. I've tried searching the entire SSD the rom is stored in and the drive Fedora itself is on for a file called `ninja.sh` to no avail. I've searched as many build-related files as I can and have not found the right file. This does not happen on Ubuntu. What could it be causing this issue?

Comment: Can you post the output of $ type mka? It will show what is mka command. It should be some modification of AOSP make or m commands. Then I can provide a suggestion for enabling debug.

Comment: You can chmod it manually, `sudo chmod ninja.sh`. Or, run this script as root: `sudo mka bacon -j12`

Comment: @ExDoors, I would say running the whole build as root is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Update: It was an issue with permissions. Adding the following fixed it:

```
pid=yourusername,gid=yourusername,umask=000,dmask=000,dmask=000
```

Comment: Where did you add it?